# Replacing values of dataframe with null values and yes and no with 1 and 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
  molecule            species
0        a              dog
1        b            horse
2        c              []
3        d             pig
4        e              []
```

I want to replace the `[]` value with `NaN` using python. How can I achieve this?

For testing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'molecule': ['a','b','c','d','e'],
    'species' : ['horse','cat','[]','frog','lion']})
```

Comment: Very similar: [Replacing blank values (white space) with NaN in pandas](/q/13445241/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'molecule': ['a','b','c','d','e'], 'species' : ['horse','cat','[]','frog','lion']})
df["species"].replace({"[]":np.nan})
```

`replace` will take dictionary where you can tell what to be mapped to what.

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace values with NAN with `DataFrame.mask()` methods. The mask() method replaces the values of the rows where the condition evaluates to True.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'molecule': ['a','b','c','d','e'], 'species' : ['horse','cat','[]','frog','lion']})
df=df.mask(df == '[]')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df.species.eq('[]'), 'species'] = np.nan
```